# Is there a way to create a sed or awk statement to replace characters in a code with characters from another range

Tags: sed, awk

Background: MS released COA labels to OEM's that had significant problems with wear.  The toner used was not bonded properly to the paper of the COA sticker.  Over time, the product key degrades and certain letters/numbers are no longer readable, prohibiting the entry of the authorized key for re-installation.

Problem: When only several of the letters/numbers are damaged, it is very frustrating to try and determine which number has been previously tried.

Request: Utilize sed or awk (preferrably) or another method to input a STRING such as

```
A{B,E,R,8}CDE-FGH{I,1}J-KLMN{O,Q,0}-PQRST-UVWXY
```

and receive the output of

```
ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
ABCDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
ABCDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
ABCDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  When you say "receive the output of",  do you mean simply print those variations to standard output?  How does that help you to "determine which number has been previously tried"?  Need a little more information.

Answer (score 5):

did you try this on the command line?  at least in bash, it "just works":

```
> echo A{B,E,R,8}CDE-FGH{I,1}J-KLMN{O,Q,0}-PQRST-UVWXY
ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY ABCDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY ABCDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY ABCDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY AECDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY AECDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY AECDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY AECDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY AECDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY AECDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY ARCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY ARCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY ARCDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY ARCDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY ARCDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY ARCDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY A8CDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY A8CDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY A8CDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY A8CDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY A8CDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY A8CDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
```

or on separate lines / used in some other command:

```
> for a in A{B,E,R,8}CDE-FGH{I,1}J-KLMN{O,Q,0}-PQRST-UVWXY; do echo $a; done
ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
ABCDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
ABCDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
ABCDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
AECDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
ARCDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGHIJ-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGHIJ-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGH1J-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGH1J-KLMNQ-PQRST-UVWXY
A8CDE-FGH1J-KLMN0-PQRST-UVWXY
```

or maybe you already knew this and need sed/awk for some other reason?

Comment: +1 - Perfect! this is exactly what I was thinking as I read the question. Also, you can do ranges: `echo {a..m}{{a..m},{s..y}}{a,d,{g..j}}`

Comment: Use tr to get multiline output: `echo A{B,E,R,8}CDE-FGH{I,1}J-KLMN{O,Q,0}-PQRST-UVWXY | tr ' ' '\n'`

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably pick Ruby, Python, or Perl for this instead. And if it were just for me, I'd do something super-cheap and use a series of nested `for` loops like the following pseudo-code:

```
string = "A%sCDE-FGH%sJ-KLMN%s-PQRST-UVWXY"

for a in ["B", "E", "R", "8"]
  for b in ["I", "1"]
    for c in ["O" "Q", "0"]
        printf string, a, b, c
    end
  end
end
```

The downside is you'd need to replace the string, the list of characters in each `for` loop, and potentially add or remove `for` loops based on the number of unknown characters. Making it a more powerful tool as you've described would definitely take more effort, but might make all the difference if you're trying to make a tool for others to use.